# Software not recognizing VLAN interfaces - Virtual Interfaces w/ tags (Intel I217-LM)

Tags: network-adapter, vlan

I am trying to manage different pieces of equipment, on a contained network, which is seperated into a few VLANs (VID: 1 - Management, 2 - Auto-Voip, 50 - Control - 51 - Dante). Some of the software I use requires me to select the network interface I would like to search on (Specific software: Riedel AVB tool, Audinate Dante controller, Netgear SmartSwitch, etc).

What I have been doing thus far:
Configure Local Area Connection in the VLAN section to create a new LAN interface that is tagged for the VLAN I want. Repeat processor for all tagged, and untagged ID. 
Connect laptop to the switch port that I have configured as a trunk for managing all VLAN's devices. 
If I need to use some software, I have to delete all VLANs, and unbridge the network adapter.

Does anyone know if there is a better way to do this or some way of making it so I don't have to keep deleting and recreating the VLANs? The biggest issue is one of time - creating each VLAN takes about 1-2 minutes. So by the time I have my computer set up, I have already spent 10 minutes just making it so I can connect to devices. Deleting the VLANs takes about 3 minutes a piece (really, I go grab coffee if I have to do delete). Untagging a few ports, and using them as VLAN management has worked, but the network switch is difficult to access...

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: What "VLAN section" exactly are you talking about? Hyper-V, or something Ethernet-manufacturer-specific, I assume?

Comment: Virtual network connection - specifically the way Intel allows you to tag your NIC. There is a tab of the properties on my main network interface - it allows me to create "Virtual Interface" ports that are tagged with specific VLAN tags (which I have been using to connect to the VLANs on my network through a trunk port I created). Basically I have three buildings, which each of a control system with "devices" this group of devices has been given a specific VLAN that they are talking on - mainly because I wanted those devices separate from our normal PCs/work equipment.

Comment: We also have our Voice VLAN, which is set up for SIP devices. This is managed by a third party (Broadcom server, hosted, etc etc), we have the "Auto-VOIP" which is configured out three netgear switches as VLAN 2 - setup based on configuration done by Biamp in their factory for an AVB network for music, paging, messaging, weather tones, etc (we have loud speakers around the entire three building group). Last, we have a VLAN for Dante (also audio, but more as a test of which pushes audio better - Dante or AVB).

Comment: Now - this is not at all part of the issue, but just a little background on what I am trying to do. For ease of configuration and troubleshooting if things aren't working, I want to be able to connect to each of those VLANs to be able to see the equipment (either be able to telnet, ping, or use 3rd party software to connect).

Comment: My issue is that when I set up my network card with three virtual interfaces (Call them Local Area Connect 2, Local Area Connection 3, etc) and then I tag them within the Intel configuration tool (network -> right click interface -> preferences -> configure -> VLANs) Some software sees them as valid network interfaces, and some software give me a "No valid network interface found" message.

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a way I can either work around this, if there is a better pieces of software/utility to tag or create interfaces with, or if I am just doing something stupid and plain wrong. - I haven't tried spinning up a few VMs yet, so that might be an option, but I just wanted to ask first.  Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same configuration and bumped into the same issue.
I found on the web that Dante does not support VLAN tagging. As a consequence the Dante Controller software ignores the VLAN tagged Ethernet adapters that I created on my PC. I guess it enumerates only physical interfaces and when it sees that the physical Ethernet adapter that supports my VLAN has a number of network protocols disabled (a consequence of having it support virtual adapter which expose those particular protocols enabled), it ignores this adapter.
Solutions found:
- add an Ethernet adapter (USB to Ethernet for instance) to handle the Dante Controller
- use another PC to host Dante Controller.
And of course, in any case, connect the solution you pick to an untagged port of the Dante VLAN.